# same length modules are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Let $M,N$ be two $R$-modules of finite length.
Let $l$ denote the length of a module.

> Is it true that if $l(M)=l(N)$ then $M \cong N$?

Comment: Canonical 'what have you tried?' comment

Comment: Consider two cyclic groups of orders $p^n$ and $q^n$ for distinct primes $p$ and $q.$